# Symfony How Get ID Inside of Controller

Tags: php, object, symfony, doctrine

I am still learning symfony, so any help with this issue would be great!

I have 3 tables: Reconciliation, ReconciliationItems, and Products.

Reconciliation stores all my reconciliation reports.

ReconciliationItems stores all the items that go into the reports.

Products stores all the product information for the ReconciliationItems.

**ReconciliationItems Table Basic Layout**

```
 --------------------------------------
 id | product_id | reconciliation_id | 
 --------------------------------------
 1  | 1000       | 4                 |
 --------------------------------------
```

id = id in the reconciliationItems table.

product_id = relates to the id in the products table. This column uses a many to one relationship to grab the id when I persist the data it to the db.

reconciliation_id = relates to the id in the reconciliation table

**My issue is:**

I am not able to directly grab the "product_id" inside of my controller when I access the repository for "ReconciliationItems".

**Here is my code:**

```
 $getReconciliationRecords = $em->getRepository('WICReconciliationItemBundle:ReconciliationItem')->find(1);
 echo $productId = getReconciliationRecords->getProduct();
```

**Here is the error I get:**

```
 Catchable Fatal Error: Object of class Proxies\__CG__\WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product could not be converted to string in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/symfonydev/src/WIC/ReconciliationBundle/Controller/ReconciliationController.php line 187
```

I am sure that I am not able to grab the product_id directly from the ReconciliationItems table because the data for that information is stored in an object. I am just not sure how to get the object data to get my product id. Please educate me :)

Thanks for any help that you guys can provide!

Comment: If you delete that echo....the error gone?

Comment: But I need to see what the ID is before I run any more scripts inside of my controller.

Comment: $checkReconciliationRecords->getProduct()->getId() Figured it out! :)

Answer (score 2):

this is called lazy loading, it means every time you query for a reconciliationitem model symfony automatically careates two proxy objects one product and one reconciliation.

the first time you try to access this objects symfony silently excutes one more query and retrive the coresponing model with the same id as product so in order to access id you should do as fallow:

```
$ReconciliationRecord->getProduct()->getId()
```

you can learn more at : http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

Answer (score 1):

```
$checkReconciliationRecords->getProduct()->getId()
```

Figured it out! :)